# Restrictions on repeated use of initial conditions in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

It seems to be common practice when solving ODE's to keep a count of what conditions you have used. I was under the impression that once a condition has been used it cannot be used again.

However, I have been considering the following Ordinary Differential Equation:

$ xf''(x) - xf'(x) - f(x) = 0 \quad$ 
with
$\quad f(0)=0 $ , $\quad f'(0) = 3$

---

Applying Laplace Transforms ***using each initial condition***, then get the following separable ODE:

$ (s-s^2)F' -2sF = 0$.

This ODE has general solution $F = k(s-1)^{-2}$.

If we apply the inverse Laplace Transform we obtain the following general solution:

$f(x) = kxe^x$.

If we use our second initial condition $f'(0) = 3$, we get $k = 3$, so

$f(x) = 3xe^x$.

---

Obviously this upsets the rough rule of thumb of 'once you use the condition once, it won't be useful again'. Obviously this is a poor rule of thumb, but I'm just wondering if there's a deeper reason for this, and what a more correct but similar rule of thumb would look like. The answer is probably obvious enough, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This initial value problem is tricky because the ODE has a singularity at $x=0$ (the coefficient  of the highest order term $f''$ vanishes there), which is exactly where the initial conditions are given. This is the underlying reason for the unusual pattern in computations.

In more concrete terms, you haven't *really* used the condition $f'(0)=3$ when obtaining the Laplace transform of the equation. Just repeat the computation with $f'(0)=a$ where $a$ is any number; the result is the same. Indeed, $a$ appears only in $\mathcal L[f''] = s^2F(s)-a$, but this gets differentiated in $s$ due to the factor of $x$ next to $f''$.

So the rule of thumb wasn't really contradicted. And it's a good one: it says that when solving an $n$th order ODE, we need $n$ linear conditions to reduce the dimension of the space of candidates for $f$ from $n$ to $0$. Once a linear condition has been imposed, it reduces the space by one dimension, and after that it's not useful: within the remaining subspace it already holds. In the above example, it's more like you used $0\cdot f'(0)= 0\cdot 3$, which doesn't reduce the space of eligible solutions.